# Stacking scatter plots with different y-axes in pgftex

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to create a stack of scatter plots with a common x-axis but different y-axes, alternating between left and right sides. I'm just learning pgfplots and while I've read up on using multiple y-axes, I haven't worked out how to stagger them like this. I've included an example of what I'm after below.

The vertical dashed lines are not necessarily required, in this case, they represent a secondary x-value for each data point.

(Plot from: Sigl et al. 2013. J. Geophys. Res. Atmos. 118:1151-1169)

[image: From: Sigl et al. 2013. J. Geophys. Res. Atmos. 118:1151-1169]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.